# How to prevent a script from reading other scripts

Tags: php

Ok, so I have linux hosting for my php site.

I have googled for a good while, but I cannot come up with the answer.

How would I make a script that I could insert some PHP code, but the script could not read or write to other files, especially higher level files?

I understand that allowing executable code inputted into a file is dangerous, but I was wondering someone knew the best way to prevent it from reaching outside the file.

Comment: this should be done with the appropriate *nix user\file\directory permissions settings - but its an odd request - can you explain why you want to do this?

Comment: lol fine, I admit its a terrible idea that I am trying to make feasible. I am attempting to build a script that will allow me to execute PHP code that I input. So, basically, it will take user input, validate the heck out of it and then evaluate the code. I would preferably not like to rely on my regex validation. I would be much more comfortable if I could block access to other files in another way.

Comment: yup - terrible idea, however have a look at one of the open source codepads (https://github.com/Viper-7/Deployable-PHP-Codepad), that should give you an idea of how to secure it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How would I make a script that I could insert some PHP code, but the script could not read or write to other files, especially higher level files?

On shared webhosting - without access to the root level - this is going to be impossible.

By default, PHP scripts will be running under a specific user account. That user account (often the webserver's) *has* to have access to all PHP files. There is no combination of rights settings that can change this fundamental fact.

Comment: I think I am just going use another one of my servers as the middle man to jail it. Thanks for saving me time.